# How to generate production sha1 key for Android?

Tags: android, sha1, production-environment, google-signin, android-keystore

I am building an android application where I am using google login. I earlier I have generated debug sha1 certificate key and it was working fine used below code - `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Now I need to generate production. Could anyone help me to figure this out how to generate SHA1 key for production release.